# How to regex split, but keep the split string?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following URL pattern:

```
http://www.hulu.jp/watch/589851/supernatural-dub-hollywood-babylon/en
```

I would like to get everything up until and inclusive of `/watch/\d+/`.

So far I have:

```
>>> re.split(r'watch/\d+/', 'http://www.hulu.jp/watch/589851/supernatural-dub-hollywood-babylon/en')
['http://www.hulu.jp/', 'supernatural-dub-hollywood-babylon/en']
```

But this does not include the split string (the string which appears between the domain and the path). The end answer I want to achieve is:

```
http://www.hulu.jp/watch/589851
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use capture group :

```
>>> re.split(r'(watch/\d+/)', 'http://www.hulu.jp/watch/589851/supernatural-dub-hollywood-babylon/en')
['http://www.hulu.jp/', 'watch/589851/', 'supernatural-dub-hollywood-babylon/en']
```

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the other answer, you need to use groups to capture the "glue" between the split strings.

I wonder though, is what you want here a `split()` or a `search()`?  It looks (from the sample) that you're trying to extract from a URL everything from the first occurrence of `/watch/XXX/` where `XXX` is 1 or more digits, to the end of the string.  If that's the case, then a match/search might be more suitable, as with a split if the search regex can match multiple times you'll split into multiple groups.  Ex:

```
re.split(r'(watch/\d+/)', 'http://www.hulu.jp/watch/589851/supernatural-dub-hollywood-babylon/watch/2342/fdsaafsdf')
['http://www.hulu.jp/', 'watch/589851/', 'supernatural-dub-hollywood-babylon/', 'watch/2342/', 'fdsaafsdf']
```

Which doesn't look like what you want.  Instead perhaps:

```
result = re.search(r'(watch/\d+/)(.*)', 'http://www.hulu.jp/watch/589851/supernatural-dub-hollywood-babylon/watch/2342/fdsaafsdf')
result.groups() if result else []
```

which gives:

```
('watch/589851/', 'supernatural-dub-hollywood-babylon/watch/2342/fdsaafsdf')
```

You could also use this approach combined with [named groups](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) to get extra fancy:

```
result = re.search(r'(?P<watchId>watch/\d+/)(?P<path>.*)', 'http://www.hulu.jp/watch/589851/supernatural-dub-hollywood-babylon/watch/2342/fdsaafsdf')
result.groupdict() if result else {}
```

giving:

```
{'path': 'supernatural-dub-hollywood-babylon/watch/2342/fdsaafsdf', 'watchId': 'watch/589851/'}
```

If you're set on the `split()` approach, you can also set the `maxsplit` parameter to ensure it's only split once:

```
re.split(r'(watch/\d+/)', 'http://www.hulu.jp/watch/589851/supernatural-dub-hollywood-babylon/watch/2342/fdsaafsdf', maxsplit=1)
```

giving:

```
['http://www.hulu.jp/', 'watch/589851/', 'supernatural-dub-hollywood-babylon/watch/2342/fdsaafsdf']
```

Personally though, I find that when parsing URL's into constituent parts the `search()` with named groups approach works extremely well as it allows you to name the various parts in the regex itself, and via `groupdict()` get a nice dictionary you can use for working with those parts.

Answer (score 0):

You've surely seen [**the** Stack Overflow don't-parse-HTML-with-regex post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1763356), yes?

> You can't parse [X]HTML with regex. Because HTML can't be parsed by regex. Regex is not a tool that can be used to correctly parse HTML. As I have answered in HTML-and-regex questions here so many times before, the use of regex will not allow you to consume HTML.

Well, regex *can* parse URLs, but trying to do so when there's a plethora of better tools is foolish.

This is what a regex for URLs looks like:

`^(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/[^\s]*)?$` (+ caseless flag)

It's just a mess of characters, right? *Exactly!*

**Don't parse URLs with regex...** *almost.*

There is one simple thing:

> A path-relative URL must be zero or more path segments separated from each other by a "/".

Splitting the URL should be as simple as `url.split("/")`.

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlunparse

myurl = "http://www.hulu.jp/watch/589851/supernatural-dub-hollywood-babylon/en"

# Run a parser over it
parts = urlparse(myurl)

# Crop the path to UP TO length 2
new_path = str("/".join(parts.path.split("/")[:3]))

# Unparse
urlunparse(parts._replace(path=new_path))
#>>> 'http://www.hulu.jp/watch/589851'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try following regex

```
.*\/watch\/\d+
```

[Working Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hK9vT0/1)